# Как на письме изображается звук, который Боярский в песне «Ланфрен-ланфра» произносит или который делается, когда что-то вкусно?

Tags: фонетика

Как на письме изображается звук, который Боярский в песне «Ланфрен-ланфра» произносит или который делается, когда что-то вкусно?

> М-м-м.

> Ым-ым-ым.

> Ум-ум-ум.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как хотите. Звукоподражание не имеет твёрдых правил и зависит от того, как вы слышите. Но в этой песне чёткое "м-м-м".